# Group (mathematics) Conjecture

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, conjectures

Given $(G,•)$ as a Group with finite set $G$, operator •.

**Define**: subset $S \subset G$ is called the *core* of the Group **if and only if**

$$ \{ x•y ~|~  x \in S, y \in S \} = G \setminus S$$

Conjecture 1: if $G$ has at least two elements,  *core* exists.

Conjecture 2: if *core* exists, any two *cores* have the same cardinality.

Conjecture 2.1: given prime $p \ge 3$, for $G = \{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$ and operator • is 'multiplication modulo p', then any *core* $S \subset G$ has cardinality $(p-1)/2$.

Example: 
$p = 7$, $S = \{3,5,6\}$

$1 \equiv 3*5 \equiv 6*6\pmod{7}$

$2 \equiv 3*3 \equiv 5*6\pmod{7}$

$4 \equiv 3*6 \equiv 5*5 \pmod{7}$

Question: anyone can find any (related) reference of the definition of *core*?

Comment: Can we have some motivation as to why we care about this construction? That might help in finding references.

Comment: Are you asking for help with proving the conjectures?  Or are you just searching for corroborating references?

Comment: It looks like in the context of example $\mathbb Z_p^*$, the multiplicative group modulo a prime, that your subset $S$ consists of the quadratic nonresidues mod $p$.  Searching on "quadratic residue" will turn up a lot of links to this classic number theory topic.

Comment: @Don Thousand
I came up this when studying the sequences containing no 3-term arithmetic progressions (Check Szekeres's sequence, A003278).
For any two numbers $a$ and $b$ from the sequence, $2a-b$, $2b-a$, $(a+b)/2$ must not appear in the sequence.

Comment: @Dohleman
I am just searching for corroborating references.

Comment: @hardmath
You are right, thanks. But also needs to prove that $a*b$ does not appear in the set.

Comment: @Kevin: That is a well-known property of quadratic (non)residues.

Comment: First, there's a standard unrelated definition of core of a subgroup in a group. Let's forget this. Second, you shouldn't say "the core of the group $G$", but "a core in the group $G$". "The" would mean you define some subset, as we can define "the center of $G$", while you define "a proper subgroup of $G$", etc.

Answer (score 6):

**Note.** *Core* already has a meaning in Group Theory: given a group $G$, the “core of a subgroup $H$” is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$. Since your set $S$ can never contain the identity, it can never be a subgroup, so this meaning of “core” is antithetical to the standard meaning. Please consider changing the name.

*Conjecture 1* is false. Consider the cyclic group of order $3$, generated by $x$. If $S$ were a “core” of $G$, then it cannot contain $e$ (since $e\bullet e = e\notin G-S$). Now, if $x\in S$, then $x^2=x\bullet x\notin S$; and if $x^2\in S$, then $x=x^2\bullet x^2\notin S$. Thus, $S$ would have to be either empty (in which case it cannot satisfy your condition) or else $S$ contains exactly one element, in which case $\{s\bullet t\mid s,t\in S\}$ contains exactly one element, and cannot be equal to $G-S$.

It is true that the quadratic nonresidues form a set as given. More generally, if $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of index $2$, then $G-H$ works as a set $S$, since $H$ is normal and $G/H$ is cyclic of order $2$; thus the product of two elements not in $H$ is always in $H$, and every element of $H$ can be expressed that way: take $h\in H$, $x\notin H$; then $x^{-1}(xh) = h$ is a product of two things in $G-H$.

*Conjecture 2* is also false. Consider $G=S_3$. As noted above, if we take $H=\{e, (1,2,3), (1,3,2)\}$ which is a subgroup of index $2$, then $S=G-H = \{(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)\}$ will satisfy $SS=G-H$. However, so does $S’=\{(1,2), (1,2,3)\}$: indeed, we obtain the other four elements as the products (I compose permutations right-to-left):
$$\begin{align*}
(1,2)(1,2) &= e\\
(1,2)(1,2,3) &= (2,3)\\
(1,2,3)(1,2) &= (1,3)\\
(1,2,3)(1,2,3) &= (1,3,2).
\end{align*}$$
That is, $(S’)(S’) = G-S’$. However, $S$ has three elements and $S’$ has two.